# Need an example showing how to do async HTTP requests

Tags: android, http, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Im using a web service, so I want to use an async thread for the HTTP authentication request and another thread later to make additional service requests while my main thread runs.

Would like to see a good example of how to do this and how to show busy messages somehow in main app. How does the main app know when the thread finished? And what if my thread encounters exceptions, how do I deal with that?

HTTP requests are sent later, use the same cookies setup up by the first auth request, so will the later requests pick up the same cookies and just work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at here [How to execute web request in its own thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022170/how-to-execute-web-request-in-its-own-thread)

Answer (score 6):

Even better look here for the async part: [Is there an accepted best-practice on making asynchronous HTTP requests in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828280/is-there-an-accepted-best-practice-on-making-asynchronous-http-requests-in-androi)

Answer (score 1):

AndroidAsync library I wrote to handle this automatically, it will run in the background and reinvoke onto the UI thread:

https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync

```
// url is the URL to download. The callback will be invoked on the UI thread
// once the download is complete.
AsyncHttpClient.getDefaultInstance().get(url, new AsyncHttpClient.StringCallback() {
    // Callback is invoked with any exceptions/errors, and the result, if available.
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
        if (e != null) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("I got a string: " + result);
    }
});
```