# onPostExecute() gets called but it wont dismiss my dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a class which extends AsyncTask, which is intended to serve as a generic task manager class for my application.

**Problem**:The strange behavior is that the progress dialog shows up, but is never dismissed.

- I am sure that onPostExecute() gets called for every task instance, as any Log.d("","") statements fire if placed in here, even the Toast messages show up from within this method, but I am not able to dismiss the static dialog.
- I understand that AsyncTask(s) have access to UI thread at only 2 places [onPreExecute() and onPostExecute()], so I think trying to dismiss the dialog in runOnUiThread() is unnecessary.
- All calls to executeTask() are made from different onCreate() methods of different activities that need to fetch some data over network before populating some of their UI elements, and I always pass the current activity's context to the tasks.
- As I do not switch activities until after the related tasks are completed, I believe the activity context objects are still valid (am I wrong to have assumed this???) I have never found any of them to be null while debugging.
- Could this be a timing issue? I have also observed that most of the times DDMS shows all tasks get completed **before** the activity is displayed. If I use `new Handler().postDelayed(runnable_which_calls_these_tasks,10);` in the onCreate(), and add delaying code in foo_X(), the activities are displayed without any delay, but the dialog will just not dismiss().

I have read through quite a number of articles on this issue but am still not able to figure out exactly where am I going wrong. I do not want to define each task as `private inner class Task1 extends AsyncTask<>`  in all of my activity classes and I would not want to (unless this is the only solution) load my application object with all activity references either as mentioned in this discussion: [Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-massively-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something).

I have spent a week on this and am absolutely clueless :( It would be great if someone can guide me, and let me know what am I missing.
Following is the class definition: [I've removed some irrelevant application specific code for clarity]

```
public class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {  

private  Context UIcontext;  
private int operationType;  
private static ProgressDialog dialog;
private static int taskCount;


private NetworkTask(int operationType Context context){  
    this.UIcontext = context; 
    this.operationType = operationType;
    if (taskCount++ == 0)  
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"","Loading...");

}  

public static Boolean executeTask(int operationType, Context context) {
    return new NetworkTask(operationType, context).execute().get(); 
}

@Override  
protected void onPreExecute(){  
    super.onPreExecute();  
    if (taskCount == 1)  
        dialog.show();  
}  

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {  
switch(operationType){  
    case TYPE_1:  
        foo1();  
        break;  
    case TYPE_2:  
        foo2();  
        break;  
    case TYPE_3:  
        foo3();  
        break;  
    case TYPE_4:  
        foo4();  
        break;  
}  

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    taskCount--;
    if (dialog.isShowing() && taskCount == 0){
            dialog.dismiss();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(UIcontext, "Task#"+ operationType+", m done, but there are "+taskCount+" more", 5).show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited:**

Mystery solved - this one was giving me a bit of trouble. There were a few problems:

1. The main problem why dialog was not showing was [`NetworkTask.get()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29). This is a blocking call that waits for the whole NetworkTask to finish. During that time it blocks UI thread so nothing is drawn (also other UI elements are unresponsive). Remove `get()`:

   ```
   public static Boolean executeTask(int operationType, Context context){
       new NetworkTask(operationType, context).execute();
       return true; // return whatever
   }
   ```
2. The `show()` on ProgressDialog is called twice. This shows two dialogs, one after another. Remove `show()` inside `onPreExecute()`.
3. ProgressDialog is modal - it prevents changing UI until it is done. `Toast.makeText()` are called before `dialog.dismiss()` but since dialog is blocking drawing to screen, they get queued and are shown after dialog is dismissed.
4. `super.onPostExecute(result)` and `super.onPreExecute()` are redundant so can be removed.

I can post the whole working code if you have trouble with it.

Comment: @Peter As I mentioned earlier, I want to manage all of my network tasks centrally by using this class. task count is just a static counter associated with the class [decremented on every task return , and incremented at every task spawn]. My intention is that the progress dialog is shown by the first task and dismissed by the last one.   [ just rechecked, taskCount is static in my code, sorry for the typo here]

Comment: @Peter Changed the code based on your observation, making sure that dialog is shown and dismissed exactly once. The dialog doesn't show up at all.

Comment: Please update the code above to reflect the changes you made.

Comment: @Falmarri for testing purposes I changed all fooX() to look like this `private void foo1() {  try { Thread.sleep(15000); }catch (Exception e) { } // network tasks done here}` shouldn't this ensure that tasks will take way too much time to execute therefore each onPostExecute() is called after a long time? UI elements load up, there is a significant delay (due to sleeping thread) and then the toasts appear, but I don't see the dialog.

Comment: @Peter  Awesome! works like a charm now :)  Now I understand why the activity was taking ages to load despite separating lengthy operations as AsyncTask. With get() I was effectively executing all of my operations serially.  A quick question though, can you point out an instance when we would want to use `get()`? Doesn't blocking indefinitely defeat the purpose of AsyncTask altogether? To me, `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` makes much more sense, as we can probably "afford" to wait for some time, in the context of our application. Thank you again for your patience :)