# How to test threads/tasks fired from activities Android

Tags: android

Look at code snippet below from my SetupActivity - how can I test that the task I fired here actually executed correctly?

For example this line:

```
new AttachChildGcmTask(app).execute(app.getChildInfo().getId());
```

Code snippet from my Activity:

```
....
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_proceed) {
        finishSetup();
    }
}


private void finishSetup() {
    UIUtilities.showToast(this, R.string.setup_completed, true);
    final AppBipper app = (AppBipper) getApplication();
    app.setSetupCompleted(true);

    Log.i(TAG, "finishSetup childId: "+app.getChildInfo().getId());
    new AttachChildGcmTask(app).execute(app.getChildInfo().getId());
    Log.i(TAG, "download settings");
    new FetchClientSettings(app).execute();

    Log.i(TAG, "cancel all scheduled alarms");
    ScheduledLocationsHelper helper =
            ScheduledLocationsHelper.getInstance(app.getDBManager(), app);
    helper.cancelAlarms();

    startActivity(new Intent(this, StartupActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking about how to write functional/unit tests?

Comment: Just did a small code formatting fix so there is no horizontal scrolling (very annoying thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean that the activity dies before the tasks are completed.

So include those tests **inside** your `AsyncTask` class and have them report to your UI somehow (Broadcasting an intent, using an handler and so on...)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, it'll probably help:

[Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something)