# How to save AsyncTask class object in onSaveInstanceState()

Tags: android

is this possible to save AsyncTask class object on rotation and reuse it again.

```
  public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
    {

    }
```

any good solution.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3359003/247013

Comment: thanks for reply but onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() deprecated after 3.0

Comment: hmm.. I missed that point, sorry.

Comment: and i am using 4.03 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this possible to save AsyncTask class object on rotation and reuse it again.

Use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` or a retained fragment.

> thanks for reply but onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() deprecated after 3.0

That is because they recommend that you use a retained fragment instead. If you are not using fragments, use `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.

Comment: i am using fragment only..for fragment save state i have used setRetainInstance(true), but i need to save state for async task class also.

Comment: @monty: Have the retained fragment hold onto the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, what's the difference if I use `onSaveInstanceState` to save `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @suitianshi: That is not possible.