# How to avoid ANR while long running XML parsing in AsyncTask of android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am downloading files from server and then parsing and inserting in local DB while this operation I am showing progress of operation using progress bar.As files is very large it's taking 2-4 mins for parsing due to this I am getting ANR on progress bar and also progress bar is not getting updated after download is completed it's showing only 50% progress.How to avoid this ANR? I am attaching my code as below...

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
            flag = false;
            progressCount = 0;
            ProgressDialog progressBar = DdownoadProgressBar(context,
            progressCount);
            progressBar.show(); 

    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls) {
        checkNetworkConnection();

        if (connectionFlag) {
            downloadFile1();
            progressCount = 1;
            publishProgress(progressCount);

            downloadFile2();
            progressCount = 2;
            publishProgress(progressCount);

            downloadFile3();
            progressCount = 3;
            publishProgress(progressCount);

            downloadFile4();
            progressCount = 4;
            publishProgress(progressCount);

            downloadFile5();
            progressCount = 5;
            publishProgress(progressCount);

            downloadFile6();
            progressCount = 6;
            publishProgress(progressCount);

            downloadflag = true;
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
    {
        Log.v(TAG, "In progressUpdate...");

        progressBar.setProgress(progressCount);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer progress) {
        if (downloadflag) {
            try {

                Log.v(TAG, "Inside onPostExecute....");

                 parseFile1();
                 progressCount=7;
                 publishProgress(progressCount);

                 parseFile2();
                 progressCount=8;
                 publishProgress(progressCount);

                 parseFile3();
                 progressCount=9;
                 publishProgress(progressCount);

                 parseFile4();
                 progressCount=10;
                 publishProgress(progressCount);

                 parseFile5();
                 progressCount=11;
                 publishProgress(progressCount);

                 parseFile6();
                 progressCount=12;
                 publishProgress(progressCount);

                 progressBar.dismiss();
                 Toast.makeText(SynchronizeData.this,"Data is successfully downloaded from server.......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            progressBar.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "File is not downloaded....Error in network connection...........",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v(TAG, "File is not downloaded...............");

        }
    }
```

Comment: don't parse in onPostExecute ?

Comment: I want to parse and insert in database for that purpose , I have to pass context for this so I can't do it in background....

Answer (score 1):

Move your parsing logic into the doInBackground method.  There's no reason to make the web calls on a background thread and parse on the UI thread.

Comment: As I am inserting the parsed data into local DB as soon as I get from parsing each element I need to pass context to my handler hence I can't write my parsing logic in doInBackground() method...

Answer (score 1):

As Rich said: parse files in doInBackground.

Other option is to run as many async task as you need in onPostExecute.

But if files are big you should consider using thread/queue-worker pattern/service !

Comment: exactly I want to use this pattern worker thread to carry out parsing task and make may UI thread to know that this task done and setProgress of progress bar but I don't know how to do this as I am new here , I searched but didn't get anything on this....if possible tell me how to carry out this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, What ever non UI task you are doing must be done in doInBackground() method.
If you will do a long running task in a method of AsyncTask which works in main thread then it will give you ANR.

Comment: As I am inserting the parsed data into local DB as soon as I get from parsing each element I need to pass context to my handler hence I can't write my parsing logic in doInBackground() method...

Comment: Why you are not storing parsed data in databean ?
And after parsing you can give context to your handler and store all data in db in one go.
pasring is more time taking them inserting in db.
so, First pasrse all data and then store in db.

Comment: I did this before tried to store parsed data in array list and then inserted in db in one go as the file is to large I am getting out of memory error....

Answer (score 1):

move the parsing logic to doinBackground() like below code.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
        flag = false;
        progressCount = 0;
        ProgressDialog progressBar = DdownoadProgressBar(context,
        progressCount);
        progressBar.show(); 

}

@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(String... urls) {
    checkNetworkConnection();

    if (connectionFlag) {
        downloadFile1();
        progressCount = 1;
        publishProgress(progressCount);

        downloadFile2();
        progressCount = 2;
        publishProgress(progressCount);

        downloadFile3();
        progressCount = 3;
        publishProgress(progressCount);

        downloadFile4();
        progressCount = 4;
        publishProgress(progressCount);

        downloadFile5();
        progressCount = 5;
        publishProgress(progressCount);

        downloadFile6();
        progressCount = 6;
        publishProgress(progressCount);

        downloadflag = true;
    }

    if (downloadflag) {
        try {

             parseFile1();
             progressCount=7;
             publishProgress(progressCount);

             parseFile2();
             progressCount=8;
             publishProgress(progressCount);

             parseFile3();
             progressCount=9;
             publishProgress(progressCount);

             parseFile4();
             progressCount=10;
             publishProgress(progressCount);

             parseFile5();
             progressCount=11;
             publishProgress(progressCount);

             parseFile6();
             progressCount=12;
             publishProgress(progressCount);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
{
    Log.v(TAG, "In progressUpdate...");

    progressBar.setProgress(progressCount);

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Integer progress) {

        try {

            Log.v(TAG, "Inside onPostExecute....");


             progressBar.dismiss();
             Toast.makeText(SynchronizeData.this,"Data is successfully downloaded from server.......", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using an AsyncTask, please read:
[Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something)

Briefly: calling AsyncTask from methods of Activity is conceptually flawed because a long operation may outlive the activity that started it. Such operations should be the responsibility of the Model (in MVC sense), in which case it will probably be something more serious than an AsyncTask.