# Android: How do I disable reload page on change screen orientation?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-orientation, android-screen

I have a activity. I have a process and this is very long. I changed the screen orientation (portrait to landscape), they process is start again... I want to disable onCreate() on change screen orientation.

How make I this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html. check the docs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this to your manifest under `<activity>`:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Thanks... I try the android:configChanges="orientation" but it isn't work. But this is work...

Answer (score 1):

I just added this on my activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Like this

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
   android:label="@string/myBoards"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I right assuming that you start an AsyncTask?

Please, read
[Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something)

In general, you should save the Activity state in [onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and restore in [onCreate(***Bundle savedInstanceState***)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29).

There are things that cannot be packed into a bundle, for example, an AsyncTask; you may pass such things via [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29).

And, of course, there still are static variables and member fields of the Application object.