# Nested Fragments - IllegalStateException "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception

## Background

#### Asynchronous Callbacks in Android

Trying to perform an asynchronous operation in a reliable fashion on Android is unnecessarily convoluted i.e. [Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something)

Now, this is all prior to the introduction of Fragments. With the introduction of Fragments, [onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRetainNonConfigurationInstance%28%29) has been deprecated. So the latest Google condoned hack is to use a persistent non-UI fragment that attaches/detaches from your Activity when configuration changes occur (i.e. Rotating the screen, changing language settings etc.)

Example:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23096#c4

#### IllegalStateException - Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Theoretically the hack above allows you to get around the dreaded:

```
IllegalStateException - "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"
```

because a persistent non-UI fragment will receive callbacks for onViewStateRestored() (alternatively onResume) and onSaveInstanceState() (alternatively onPause). As such you can tell when the instance state is saved/restored. It's a fair bit of code for something so simple, but utilising this knowledge, you could queue up your asynchronous callbacks until the activity's FragmentManager has its mStateSaved variable set to false before executing them.

mStateSaved being the variable who is ultimately responsible for firing this exception.

```
private void checkStateLoss() {
    if (mStateSaved) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState");
    }
    if (mNoTransactionsBecause != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Can not perform this action inside of " + mNoTransactionsBecause);
    }
}
```

So theoretically, now you know when it's safe to perform fragment transactions, and you can hence avoid the dreaded IllegalStateException.

*Wrong!*

#### Nested Fragments

The solution above only works for the Activity's FragmentManager. Fragments themselves also have a child fragment manager, which is utilised for nesting fragments. Unfortunately, child fragment managers are not kept in sync with the Activity's fragment manager at all. So whilst the activity's fragment manager is up-to-date and always has the correct mStateSaved; child fragments think otherwise and will happily throw the dreaded IllegalStateException at inappropriate times.

Now, if you've looked at Fragment.java and FragmentManager.java in the support library you won't in any way be surprised that everything and anything to do with fragments is error prone. The design and code quality is... ah, questionable. Do you like booleans?

```
mHasMenu = false
mHidden = false
mInLayout = false
mIndex = 1
mFromLayout = false
mFragmentId = 0
mLoadersStarted = true
mMenuVisible = true
mNextAnim = 0
mDetached = false
mRemoving = false
mRestored = false
mResumed = true
mRetainInstance = true
mRetaining = false
mDeferStart = false
mContainerId = 0
mState = 5
mStateAfterAnimating = 0
mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
mCalled = true
mTargetIndex = -1
mTargetRequestCode = 0
mUserVisibleHint = true
mBackStackNesting = 0
mAdded = true
```

Anyway, getting a bit off topic.

#### Dead-end solution

So, you might think the solution to the problem is simply, *which seems like a bit of an antonym at this point*, to add another one of those nice hacky non-UI fragments to your child fragment managers. Presumably its callbacks are in sync with its internal state and things will all be dandy.

*Wrong again!*

Android doesn't support retained fragment instances that are attached as children to other fragments (aka nested fragments). Now, in hindsight this should make sense. If the parent fragment is destroyed when the activity is destroyed because its not retained, there is nowhere to reattach the child fragment. So that's just not going to work.

## My Question

Does someone out there have a solution for determining when it is safe to perform fragment transactions *on child fragments* in conjunction with asynchronous code callbacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update 2

#### React Native

If you can stomach it, use React Native. I know, I know... "dirty web technologies", but in all seriousness, the Android SDK is a disaster, so swallow your pride and just give it a go. You might surprise yourself; I know I did!

#### Can't or Won't use React Native

No worries, I'd suggest fundamentally changing your approach to networking. Firing a request and running a request handler to update the UI just doesn't work well with Android's component life-cycles.

Instead try one of:

1. Move to simple message passing system based around `LocalBroadcastReceiver` and have long-living objects (regular Java classes or Android Services) do your requests and fire events when your app's local state changes. Then in your Activity/Fragment, just listen for certain `Intent` and update accordingly.
2. Use a Reactive event library (e.g. RxJava). I've not tried this myself on Android, but had pretty good success using a similar concept library, ReactiveCocoa for a Mac/desktop app. Admittedly these libraries have a fairly steep learning curve, but the approach is quite refreshing once you get used to it.

## Update 1: Quick and Dirty (Official) Solution

I believe this is latest official solution from Google. However, the solution really doesn't scale very well. If you're not comfortable messing with queues, handlers and retained instance states yourself then this may be your only option... but don't say I didn't warn you!

Android activities and fragments have support for a [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html) which can be used with [AsyncTaskLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#getLoader(int)). Behind the scenes loader managers are retained in precisely the same way as retained fragments. As such this solution does share a bit in common with my own solution below. AsyncTaskLoader is a partially pre-canned solution that does technically *work*. However, the API is extremely cumbersome; as I'm sure you'll notice within a few minutes of using it.

## My Solution

Firstly, my solution is by no means simple to implement. However, once you get your implementation working it's a breeze to use and you can customise it to your heart's content.

I use a retained fragment that is added to the Activity's fragment manager (or in my case support fragment manager). This is the same technique mentioned in my question. This fragment acts as a *provider* of sorts which keeps track of which activity it is attached to, and has Message and Runnable (actually a custom sub-class) queues. The queues will execute when the instance state is no longer saved *and* the corresponding handler (or runnable) is "ready to execute".

Each handler/runnable stores a UUID that refers to a *consumer*. *Consumers* are typically fragments (which can be nested safely) somewhere within the activity. When a *consumer* fragment is attached to an activity it looks for a *provider* fragment and registers itself using its UUID.

It is important that you use some sort of abstraction, like UUID, instead of referencing *consumers* (i.e. fragments) directly. This is because fragments are destroyed and recreated often, and you want your callbacks to have a "reference" to new fragments; not old ones that belong to a destroyed activity. As such, unfortunately, you rarely can safely use variables captured by anonymous classes. Again, this is because these variables might refer to an old destroyed fragment or activity. Instead you must ask the *provider* for the *consumer* that matches the UUID the handler has stored. You can then cast this *consumer* to whatever fragment/object it actually is and use it safely, as you know its the latest fragment with a valid Context (the activity).

A handler (or runnable) will be "ready to execute" when the *consumer* (referred to by UUID) is ready. It is necessary to check if the *consumer* is ready in addition to the *provider* because as mentioned in my question, the consumer fragment might believe its instance state is saved even though the provider says otherwise. If the consumer (or provider) are not ready then you put the Message (or runnable) in a queue in the provider.

When a *consumer* fragment reaches onResume() it informs the *provider* that it is ready to consume queued messages/runnables. At which point the *provider* can try execute anything in its queues that belong to the *consumer* that just became ready.

This results in handlers always executing using a valid Context (the Activity referenced by the provider) and the latest valid Fragment (aka "consumer").

## Conclusion

The solution is quite convoluted, however it does work flawlessly once you work out how to implement it. If someone comes up with a simpler solution then I'd be happy to hear it.

Comment: Ben, could you conceivably implement this generically, say in a new base Activity class (or a decorator)? Seems insane to jump through those loops for something which should be simple..

Comment: @RyanBarrett I've written a library for my own use, which does include an optional base Activity (for the support library). However, sometimes you don't have the luxury of inheriting from it e.g. when sub-classing a third-party activity, so I've got an interface for Activities to implement if necessary as well. Maybe I should open-source the library. The thought of encouraging such a complex solution to what *should be* a simple problem is a bit depressing though.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Regarding generics. Unfortunately it can't be (or at least I couldn't work out how it could be) implemented purely with generics, you need some casts somewhere. I definitely did try, but it was almost three years ago so I can't remember exactly what tripped me up.

Comment: Did you finally open-sourced your solution? Or did you finally found something simpler? I'm facing the same issue and  your solution seems nice, but would give me hard time to implement it.

Comment: @Shargoth, I did find something simpler, React Native. I know that might sound a bit odd, and I was (and still am when necessary) a true native mobile developer for years (since before there was an official iOS SDK). Apple's iOS frameworks are great and Swift is a nice modern language, so staying with the official tools makes sense on iOS. However, the best advice I can give for Android development is to use React Native. It's certainly not without its problems either, but the Android SDK is a complete and utter disgrace. Android itself is fantastic OS complete maimed by the lack of sane APIs.

Comment: @Shargoth, however, if you're working with an existing app (or doing something React Native can't do well just yet), here's some tips. Instead of using the described solution I ended up fundamentally changing the way I was doing my networking, I just didn't like this solution's complexity (felt over-engineered). Instead I moved to a message passing system where I'd have one or more network/state managers (regular classes) and they'd use the LocalBroadcastManager to send messages. Activity/Fragment would listen for broadcasts relevant to themselves and update their UI accordingly.

Comment: Thank's for the reply and for every details you give. I'm kind of new to React Native, I mean I'm only using it since a few months but I think I would try to achieve it this way. In meantime I found a solution to avoid my nested fragments to be nested (architectural design changes), but I appreciate the way you give real and helpful hints on how to handle this issue, I'll sure come back here if I implement a React Native solution for this kind of problem.