# WeakReference/AsyncTask pattern in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, weak-references

I have a question regarding this simple frequently occurring situation in android .

We have a main activity , we invoke an AsyncTask alongwith the reference of the mainactivity , so that that the AsyncTask can update the views on the MainActivity.

I will break down the event into steps

- MainActivity creates an AyncTask , passes its reference to it .
- AysncTask , starts it's work , downloading ten files for example
- The user changed the orientation of the device. This results in an orphan pointer in the AsyncTask
- When the AsyncTask completes , and tries to access the activity to update the status , it crashes ,   because of the null pointer .

The solution for the above is to keep a WeakReference in the AsyncTask as recommended by the book "Pro Android 4"

```
WeakReference<Activity> weakActivity;

in method onPostExecute

Activity activity = weakActivity.get();
if (activity != null) {
   // do your stuff with activity here
}
```

How does this resolve the situation ?

My question it , if my asynctask is downloading ten files , and upon completion of 5 the activity is restarted (because of an orientation change) then would my FileDownloadingTask be invoked once again ?.

What would happen to the previous AsyncTask that was initially invoked ?

Thank you  , and I apologize for the length of the question .

Comment: Thank you for posting such a well formed and worded question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> How does this resolve the situation ?

The `WeakReference` allows the `Activity` to be garbage collected, so you don't have a memory leak.

A null reference means that the `AsyncTask` *cannot* blindly try to update a user-interface that is no longer attached, which would throw exceptions (e.g. view not attached to window manager). Of course you have to check for null to avoid NPE.

> if my asynctask is downloading ten files , and upon completion of 5 the activity is restarted (because of an orientation change) then would my FileDownloadingTask be invoked once again ?.

Depends on your implementation, but probably yes - if you don't deliberately do something to make a repeat download unnecessary, such as caching the results somewhere.

> What would happen to the previous `AsyncTask` that was initially invoked ?

In earlier versions of Android it would run to completion, downloading all of the files only to throw them away (or perhaps cache them, depending on your implementation).

In newer Android's I am suspicious that `AsyncTask`'s are being killed along with the `Activity` that started them, but my basis for suspicion is only that the memory-leak demo's for [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) (see below) do not actually leak on my JellyBean devices.

If I may offer some advice: `AsyncTask` is not suitable for performing potentially long running tasks such as networking.

`IntentService` is a better (and still relatively simple) approach, if a single worker thread is acceptable to you. Use a (local) `Service` if you want control over the thread-pool - and be careful not to do work on the main thread!

[RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) seems good if you are looking for a way to reliably perform networking in the background (disclaimer: I have not tried it; I am not affiliated). There is a [RoboSpice Motivations demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.octo.android.robospice.motivations) in the play store which explains *why* you should use it by demo-ing all the things that can go wrong with `AsyncTask` - including the WeakReference workaround.

See also this thread: [Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something)

Update:

I created a [github project](https://github.com/steveliles/Android-Download-Service-Example) with an example of downloading using `IntentService` for another SO question ([How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)), but it is also relevant here, I think. It has the added advantage that, by returning the result via `onActivityResult`, a download that is in flight when you rotate the device will deliver to the restarted `Activity`.

Comment: Little update: By now RxJava is a great way to run tasks in the background, off the main thread and have your results delivered on the main thread (so you can update the UI etc). Another option would be using an EventBus,

Answer (score 7):

The `WeakReference` class basically just prevents the JRE to increase the reference counter for the given instance.

I won't go into Java's memory management and answer your question directly: The `WeakReference` resolves the situation by providing the `AsyncTask` a way to learn if its parent activity is still valid.

The orientation change itself will not automatically restart the `AsyncTask`. You have to code the desired behavior with the known mechanisms (`onCreate`/`onDestroy`, `onSave/RestoreInstanceState`).

Concerning the original `AsyncTask`, I'm not 100 % sure which of these options will happen:

- Either Java stops the thread and disposes the `AsyncTask`, because the only object holding a reference to it (the original `Activity`) is destroyed
- Or some internal Java object maintains a reference to the `AsyncTask` object, blocking its garbage collection, effectively leaving the `AsyncTask` to finish in the background

Either way, it would be good practice to abort/pause and restart/resume the `AsyncTask` manually (or handing it over to the new `Activity`), or use a `Service` instead.

Comment: WeakReference is not useful when you are using AsyncTask inner class of Activity

Answer (score 2):

> How does this resolve the situation ?

**It doesn't.**

The referent of a `WeakReference` is set to `null` when the garbage collector determines that the referent is weakly reachable. This does not happen when an activity is paused, and does not necessarily happen immediately when the activity is destroyed and the framework discards all references to it. If the GC has not run, it is entirely possible for the `AsyncTask` to complete while its `WeakReference` still contains a reference to a dead activity.

Not only that, but this approach does nothing to prevent the `AsyncTask` from uselessly consuming CPU.

A better approach is to have the `Activity` maintain a strong reference to the `AsyncTask` and [`cancel(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)) it in the appropriate teardown lifecycle method.  The `AsyncTask` should monitor [`isCancelled()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#isCancelled()) and stop working if it is no longer needed.

If you want an `AsyncTask` to survive across configuration changes (but *not* other forms of activity destruction) you can host it in a retained fragment.