# why should be better to use weakreference

Tags: java, android

I saw many place using WeakReference like below,  what's the reason to use like this? 
Is it must to be use like that in this senario?

```
public class MyActivity extends Actiivity {

 private class InitServiceRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        WeakReference<MyActivity> mActivityRef;
        public InitServiceRunnable(MyActivity activity)
        {
            mActivityRef = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() { /* using mActivityRef here */}
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297378/weakreference-asynctask-pattern-in-android this might help

Comment: a good example:http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CanonicalizedMapping