# Passing a reference to an Activity in Asynctask defined as a separate Class , Will it lead to memory Leak if Activity is killed by User

Tags: android

Passing a reference to an Activity in  Asynctask defined as a separate Class , Will it lead to memory Leak if Activity is killed by User (Please don't consider screen rotation Scenarios im aware of that)

Comment: what are you trying to do with the activity reference?

Comment: Im  using it to initialize an interface to send callback back to activity

Answer (score 1):

I've always read that in this scenario you should use a [`WeakReference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to the `Activity`, so that the `Activity` can be properly garbage collected iff there are no other hard references to it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18309382/1541763) explains it much better than I could.

Comment: I understand Weak References but Im doubtful as to how early that weak reference gets garbage collected , they have a mind of their own

Comment: Rather than that why not create a new method that onCancel(Asynctask) in which we can pass the asynctask reference and cancel it and then set the interface reference to null

Comment: You never have precise control over when the garbage collector does its job, but as soon as an object is only reachable by weak references, it is eligible to be collected. In the case study I read on garbage collection, objects with only weak references were collected after all objects with no references were collected, at a rate proportional to the memory pressure on the system.