# Starting singleTask activity every few seconds gives ANR in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

In the app I have an activity which has launch mode as singleTask. There are number of use cases which pass through this activity and hence it's called number of times. On stress testing the app by running monkeyrunner script and calling this activity every few seconds causes ANR's.

I guess, the way it's designed where most of the use cases pass through this activity is not correct but I am not in a position to change this design.

Is there anyway ANR's can be suppressed? I mean, adding UI operations to event queue so that it doesn't block main UI thread and doesn't give ANR.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from the question what your activity is (or should be) doing. Probably you need a service instead.

It is common to perform time-consuming operations in background threads and deliver the results to the UI thread.

You may use the classes [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)/[`Looper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) (it it easir to send `Runnable`s rather than messages), or use an `AsyncTask`. The `AsyncTask` is nevertheless tricky, this is discussed here: [Is AsyncTask really conceptually flawed or am I just missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something) . AFAIK Google tried to fix the typical bugs and made the new behavior incompatible with the old one (namely, I have seen some misbehavior on the newer Androids that may be explained by the assumption that since some version threads doing asynctask jobs get killed after the activity that started them goes out of the screen).

I can guess that `singleTask` is your way to fight the fact that an activity dies when the screen turns, and a new one comes. I suggest you use singletons (they survive screen rotation but do not survive a process restart, one more thing that sometimes happens in Android). (The user switches to an app like Camera, takes a big photo, returns back -- and the activity is restarted because Camera needed memory. Have seen this in practice, but that time I did not try to find out if the whole process  was restarted.)

Anyway, please add logging telling you when your activity in entered and left, including `onNewIntent()` and other lifecycle functions (to be on the safe side, I recommend to print the thread names as well). Then you will probably see what is going on.