# Clean way to retain CoroutineScope through config changes without ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I know the recommendation is to use a ViewModel with our Activity, so we can use its `viewModelScope`. Since the ViewModel outlives the Activity, we don't have to cancel our jobs in `activity.onDestroy()`.

However, sometimes you have a dirt-simple Activity. For example, it could populate a list view with filtered packages that are installed. You can very simply create a scope for the activity using a delegate, and cancel jobs in `onDestroy()`:

```
class MyActivity(): AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope by MainScope() {

    private val listAdapter = MyAdapter()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity)
        recycler_view.apply {
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            adapter = listAdapter
        }
        launch {
            val packages = getOrgPackagesWithIcons()
            adapter.apply {
                data = packages
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        cancel() // CoroutineContext
    }

    private suspend fun getOrgPackagesWithIcons() = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        var toNextYield = 20
        packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0)
            .filter { it.packageName.startsWith("org")
            .take(100)
            .map { 
                     if (--toNextYield == 0) { // Make it cancellable
                         toNextYield = 20
                         yield()
                     }
                     MyPackageData(
                         it.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager).toString(),
                         it.packageName,
                         it.applicationInfo.loadIcon(packageManager)
                     )
                 }
        }

}
```

For a case like this, ViewModel feels like overkill. It would just be another layer to abstract the PackageManager, which is really a view model in itself.

The above code makes it easy to assemble the data in the background. The problem is that when the screen is rotated, or during other configuration changes, the coroutine is cancelled and restarted. Is there a clean recipe for keeping a CoroutineScope alive through a configuration change for a very simple Activity like this?

`onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` is deprecated. I suppose we could put it in a Fragment and use `retainInstance = true`, but introducing a Fragment layer to such a simple Activity also feels like overkill.

Maybe there's a way to create an empty ViewModel implementation just so we can borrow its scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For a case like this, ViewModel feels like overkill.

I would argue otherwise and still suggest this would be a good use case for [`AndroidViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/AndroidViewModel).

I believe that it is not the `Activity`'s responsibility to fetch the package list just because it has access to the `PackageManager`. The `Activity` should only be responsible for displaying the list.

Using `AndroidViewModel` gives you access to `Context` and `viewModelScope` within your `ViewModel` instance.

Comment: That's a fair point. Especially in my example where I do more than a simple query, but also subsequently filter it and load icons. I consider it a design error that Activity extends Context rather than simply holding a reference to it like Fragment does. But if using an AndroidViewModel, how do you tie it to a specific Activity that might get re-instantiated? You would still want to cancel the associated Jobs for that Activity if it were destroyed for reasons other than configuration change.

Comment: As far as I can see, the only difference between `ViewModel` and `AndroidViewModel` is that `AndroidViewModel` gives you access to `Context` via the `Application` instance you pass into its constructor. Basically, `AndroidViewModel` just "holds" a `Context` for you to use. Job cancellation and lifecycle concerns are the same for both. If an `Activity` is destroyed due to process death (this is the first thing that came to mind that is not a config change), then neither `ViewModel` nor `AndroidViewModel` would survive that.

Comment: So where is the correct place to cancel jobs in the case where the user navigates away from the activity? Is it as simple as putting `if (isFinishing) viewModel.viewModelScope.cancel()` in `onPause()`? Not sure if `isFinishing` returns true on configuration changes.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this is more a question on how `viewModelScope` is implemented? By default, it cancels all jobs when the `ViewModel` is no longer needed, i.e. when the `ViewModel`'s `onCleared()` is called. I do not know if there is a way to manually cancel running Jobs in `onPause()` other than calling a method on the `ViewModel` that inherently calls `viewModelScope.cancel()` .

Comment: My question shifted, because I think you've convinced me that even in such a simple example, it's poor design to do data acquisition in a UI class like Activity. Re-familiarizing myself with ViewModel, I see that it already behaves as I would want, automatically cancelling jobs when the owning activity is finished (but not when there's a configuration change). If you have data that needs to outlive specific Activities, you can create a repo singleton class that retrieves its instance with an Application reference, and you can use AndroidViewModel's `application` instance to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the above answer that ViewModel is still the best choice here because you are performing data operations which don't really belong in the activity. That said, if you look into the *how* `ViewModel` retains data - its simple static. Not quoting the full chain here, just the part where it all comes together

```
if (mViewModelStore == null) {
    NonConfigurationInstances nc =
            (NonConfigurationInstances) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
    if (nc != null) {
        // Restore the ViewModelStore from NonConfigurationInstances
        mViewModelStore = nc.viewModelStore;
    }
    if (mViewModelStore == null) {
        mViewModelStore = new ViewModelStore();
    }
}
```

where NonConfigurationInstances is:

```
static final class NonConfigurationInstances {
    Object custom;
    ViewModelStore viewModelStore;
}
```

Putting it here to address your question re "empty ViewModel implementation" - that's how it done there, and you can do something similar - perhaps place into your own Application class. But again that said, it's there and it's simple to use and provides other benefits... so I always  use view model/androidviewmodel and there is no overhead at all in my mind, just the opposite, the code is nicely organized.

Comment: `its simple static` -- what do you mean by this? I see `mViewModelStore`, it's probably not static, and none of the snippets here show a static field declaration.

Comment: exactly, I don't get it either!